# Openlayers displaying local pbf at wrong location

Tags: openlayers, geojson, pbf

Need help for displaying of local pbf file, it does show tiles but at wrong location and when zoom-in the whole feature set split into 4 locations.

First Openlayers v 4.6.5 is not displaying local pbf file

Here is code i am trying

```
   new ol.layer.Tile({
     source:new ol.source.VectorTile({
       format: new ol.format.MVT(),
       url:"rectangle-1.0.0.pbf"
     })
   })
```

openlayers load file "rectangle-1.0.0.pbf" as i can see in "Network Tab" of Chrome Developer's tool.

try above code with this style code also but shows nothing on map

```
     style: function(feature, res) {
           return new ol.style.Style({
               stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                   width: 2,
                   color: 'rgba(0, 102, 204)'
               })
           })
       },
```

i also try latest openlayers version 5.3.0 but it gives me error "Cannot read property 'ol_uid' of undefined".

Using help from @Mike it now shows pbf tiles with this code

```
   new ol.layer.VectorTile({
     source:new ol.source.VectorTile({
       format: new ol.format.MVT(),
       url:"rectangle-1.0.0.pbf"
     })
   })
```

but at wrong location and when i zoom-in whole feature set split into 4 locations and so on.

Note: Openlayers projection must be 4326 otherwise it does not display pbf files.i am creating pbf files with the help of geojson-vt "https://github.com/mapbox/geojson-vt". (From GeoJSON to pbf).the geojson must be in 4326.

What needs to be done?

[image: zoom-in split features]

Comment: A vector tile layer works with a grid of pbf tiles  If you have a single pbf file try loading it using ol.layer.Vector and ol.source.Vector.

Comment: i tried with your idea but it gives error "Cannot read property 'toString' of null"

Comment: tried with ol.layer.VectorTile, new ol.source.VectorTile , it does show data on map, but data is not on it's original position but shifted. Can you tell me why?
Thanks

Comment: GeoJSON only has one projection and its not EPSG:4326

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are displaying the same data from rectangle-1.0.0.pbf in every tile at each zoom level, which is why you can see a repeated pattern across the map.  If you have a tile grid you need a url string containing {x} {y} and {z}.  If you only have one tile (and therefore one zoom level) you should that as the minZoom and maxZoom on the source.  I don't know what data is in your pbf file, however all I need to get a copy of the pbf in this mapbox demo https://github.com/mapbox/vt-pbf/tree/master/test/fixtures to give  similar results to the geojson link is:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    new ol.layer.VectorTile({
      source:new ol.source.VectorTile({
      format: new ol.format.MVT(),
        url:"rectangle-{z}.{x}.{y}.pbf",
        tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({minZoom: 1, maxZoom: 1})
      })
    })
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0,0],
    zoom: 0
  })
});
```

then zoom in to eastern Canada